# Finding the kth element of a permutation

Tags: permutations, randomness

Is there a way to generate a random permutation of the numbers 1 to *N* such that I can find the *k*-th element of the permuted list without needing to either 1) store the entire permuted list, or 2) compute the elements 1..*k-1*?

Comment: If you're not going to store the entire permutation, in what sense are you generating a random permutation? If all you need to know is the $k$th element of a random permutation, then just take a uniformly random element – the distribution is the same.

Comment: I'm going to be using a selection of elements from the permutation, but not neccessarily the entire permutation.

Comment: Can you specify your problem completely? Let us know what operations this data structure should support.

Comment: Agree with @YuvalFilmus. If it's a random permutation, what's the difference between 1st and kth permutation?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem statement

Your question is unclear, but here is how I interpret it:

> Input: a positive integer $n$, and $k$ distinct values $x_1,\dots,x_k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$
>   Output: the values $\pi(x_1),\pi(x_2),\dots,\pi(x_k)$, where $\pi$ is a random permutation on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

You are looking for an efficient algorithm to solve this problem.

### An efficient solution

If that is indeed what you are looking for, there is a very efficient way to solve this problem.  Basically, all you need to do is randomly choose $k$ distinct integers from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  This is sampling *without* replacement.  Here is a simple algorithm:

- Initialize $S$ to be the empty set.
- For $i=1,2,\dots,k$:

  - Pick $r$ uniformly at random from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  If $r\in S$, pick a new $r$ (and keep repeating until $r \notin S$).
  - Set $x_i$ to $r$, and add $r$ to $S$.

You can use any number of data structures for storing the set $S$; it could be a bitvector of length $n$, or a hashtable.  (A bitvector is probably better if $k$ is not too much smaller than $n$, say $k \ge n/64$ or so; a hashtable is probably more efficient if $k$ is small compared to $n$.)

### Performance analysis

If $k \le n/2$, the expected running time is linear in $n$, so this is very efficient.

If $k \ge n/2$, there are better algorithms.  For instance, once you reach $i \ge n/2$, then rather than choosely uniformly, you can choose uniformly at random from $\overline{S}$ (the complement of $S$).  If you use the right data structures, you can make the expected running time be linear in $n$.  (Basically, once $i\ge n/2$, you compute $\overline{S}$ and throw away $S$.  In each step, you choose a random element of $\overline{S}$, then remove it from $\overline{S}$.  Choosing a random element of a set can be done in $O(1)$ expected time.)

Answer (score -1):

If you rank all the n! Permutaions in some order, such as the lexicographic order, then you can unrank a number to a permutation. The procedure is simple. So given a random number in [1..n!], you can compute a random permutation.

Comment: The poster doesn't want just a random permutation, they  want the kth element of a random permutation  without storing the permutation or calculating the first k-1 values, Also why rank N! permutations when you can just shuffle the list of numbers 1 to N, ranking all permutations just to pick one random one seems convoluted and time consuming?